# Prevent unhiding columns in excel using autofit in Python

Tags: python, excel

I'm using autofit in Python script to automatically adjust width of columns in Excel file. I have hidden columns that supposed to stay hidden (but also should be formated). However, autofit function opens all hidden columns. Is there a way to prevent that?

This is how my code looks like:

```
from win32com.client import Dispatch
import openpyxl as opxl #other xl
import os 

xl = Dispatch("Excel.Application")
xl.Visible = True
dir_path = os.path.dirname(os.path.realpath(__file__)) 
r_dir = dir_path+'/WR.xlsx'
wb1 = xl.Workbooks.Open(Filename = r_dir)
WR_fn = opxl.load_workbook(r_dir)
for list_name in WR_fn.sheetnames:
    ws = wb1.Worksheets(str(list_name))
    ws.Columns.AutoFit()
wb1.Save()
print("Formating is done!")
```

Comment: Please paste all of the `import ...` statements from the beginning of your script *into your question* so that we know which modules you are using here.

Comment: Also, please paste the code itself into your question rather than uploading a screenshot of your code as you have done.